# Cocoa (MonoMac) & WinForms (or WPF) frontend with common c# backend

Tags: c#, winforms, cocoa, mono, monomac

I'm designing a desktop application (LOB type) that needs to run on MacOSX, Windows and Linux. We have been focusing on WinForms, but we have to abandon this due to instability on MacOS (Linux is pretty decent so far).

I was wondering if there were any code examples, back-end/api design guidelines and on how to accomplish this in a good manner.

The only examples I have found were either Mono/C# examples targetting one of the UI platforms - but not both.

Basically,

- design patterns to look at (MVP, MVC, MVVM)
- and how to implement them in a good way on both UI domains

Thanks,
Yves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research I've ended up with two options

- Xwt [ https://github.com/mono/xwt ];
- Eto.Forms [ https://github.com/picoe/Eto ].

Both are .Net corss platform UI toolkits, or frameworks if you like, that abstract away the concrete (platform specific) implementations of the UI.

At the time of writing

- Xwt is supporting Windows (WPF, Gtk#), MacOS (MonoMac, Gtk#) and Linux (Gtk#).
- Eto.Forms is supporting Windows (WinForms, WPF (w/ GDI+ or Direct2D) and Gtk#), MacOS (MonoMac or Xamarin.Mac), Linux (Gtk#2, Gtk#3), iOS (Xamarin.iOS). And support is announced for Android (Xamarin.Android), Windows 8.x and Windows Phone.

My choice, personally, went out to Eto.Forms because of it's strong philosophy and ease of use + good demo applications listed on their main GitHub page. But I recommend to check both out and make your own choice.

Comment: Can you share what's the main difference between these two? Do they have data binding like in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

- Xwt [ https://github.com/mono/xwt ]
- Eto.Forms [ https://github.com/picoe/Eto ]
- Avalonia [https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia]

I am not sure is there another option or not

and Eto.Forms has Data Binding and you can use MVVM:

https://github.com/picoe/Eto/wiki/Data-Binding

I am not sure about others if they have data binding or not.

### This is example how ETO can use MVVMLight and data binding :

- This is the ViewModel which has a collection of users and this ViewModel exists in portable project which is shared between Windows and Mac Project:
  [ViewModel](https://github.com/EbramSamy/Eto-MVVMLight-Example/blob/master/ETOApp/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs)
- This is the View which has a ListViw Binding to users collection and this View exists also in the portable project which is shared between Windows and Mac Project:
  [View](https://github.com/EbramSamy/Eto-MVVMLight-Example/blob/master/ETOApp/MainForm.xeto.cs)

and that means the View and ViewModel are shared between Mac and Windows Projects.

Comment: In this case it's not your fault because the question was off-topic, but please note that in general, an answer that recommends some tool or library must demonstrate how it solves the problem at hand in the answer itself.

Comment: Yes so this is a project shows how ETO can be used as a cross platform desktop and user interface framework and ===> sharing Views and ViewModels between Windows and Mac Project: https://github.com/EbramSamy/Eto-MVVMLight-Example